# Unable to open .sccs file in vs code vue3 with cmd+ click

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite

When i try to ctrl + click on @import "@/assets/scss/style.scss" or @import "../../../assets/scss/ui/input.scss" in vue 3 sfc i have error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t44LX.png).
This is incorrect behavior. If anyone knows the answer you would help me a lot.

Comment: the screenshot shows `@assets` in the path that it tried to resolve.  Did what you click have `@/assets` or `@assets` in the path? It looks like a typo involving the latter.

Comment: @yoduh Sorry. its vite alias `@assets`: fileURLToPath(new URL("./src/assets", import.meta.url)). Anyway @assets or `@/assets` doesnt work.